# Python olefile extract text of body

Tags: python, msg

I been trying to extract the text content of a msg file in the disk using python module olefile. But getting `AttributeError: OleFileIO instance has no attribute 'read'`. Tried to read olefile API but could not get any clue. Thank you.

```
import sys,olefile

x=olefile.OleFileIO('dkd.msg')

print x.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
y = x.openstream('WordDocument'); print y.read()
```